# How do I multiply values in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to find a basic input where user enters one number and the second number and then multiplies it.

I got it to work without the isset function, but now I am trying to echo out the error line when the page first starts up. If you see the input it is named, name and name2 so I call them in PHP.
My original code did not use isset and it worked but I got error before any input. This is my PHP code:

```
<html>

    <style>
        <?php include 'style.css';?>
    </style>
    <body>

        <form method="post">
            <p> Enter Value 1:<input type="text" name="name"> <br>
                <p> Enter Value 2:<input type="text" name="name2"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="send">
        </form>


        <br>
        <h3>Your input:</h3><br>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['name'])) && (isset($_POST['name2'])){
    $num=$_POST['name'];
    $num2=$_POST['name2'];
    echo $num*$num2;
}

else{
    echo '';
}


?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to check/validate their input as well because they may try and be funny and do alpha chars

Comment: waht error you are getting

Comment: how do I validate can someone give me a sample code?

Answer (score 2):

You have closed your IF parentheses too soon. The line should be like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['name2'])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working code you have some extra parenthesis. If you are multiplying integer values from user always use `intval` function so that you always have integer value. If user enters string or characters it `intval` will change to zero

```
<html>

<style>
    <?php include 'style.css';?>
</style>
<body>

    <form method="post">
        <p> Enter Value 1:<input type="text" name="name"> <br>
            <p> Enter Value 2:<input type="text" name="name2"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>


    <br>
    <h3>Your input:</h3><br>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['name2'])){
    $num  = intval($_POST['name']);
    $num2 = intval($_POST['name2']);
    echo $num*$num2;
}

else{
    echo '';
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this I think it is helpful to you:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="value1" placeholder="Enter 1st Value" required>
<input type="text" name="multiply" value="*" readonly>
<input type="text" name="value2" placeholder="Enter 2nd Value" required>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $value1 = $_POST['value1'];
    $multiply = $_POST['multiply'];
    $value2 = $_POST['value2'];

    if($multiply == "*"){
        echo $value1*$value2;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is paranthesis are not closed properly it is

```
  if(condition1)&& (condition2){
  }
```

it should be

```
  if((condition1)&&(condition2)){

  }
```

you can use single condition for this also as shown in below code

```
        <style>
            <?php include 'style.css';?>
        </style>
        <body>

            <form method="post">
                <p> Enter Value 1:<input type="text" name="name"> <br>
                    <p> Enter Value 2:<input type="text" name="name2"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="send" name="send">
            </form>


            <br>
            <h3>Your input:</h3><br>

    <?php

    //if (isset($_POST['name'])) && (isset($_POST['name2'])){  problem is here your paranthesis are not closed properly
    if (isset($_POST['send'])){ //use this as this will ensure that your send button is clicked for submitting form
        $num=$_POST['name'];
        $num2=$_POST['name2'];
        echo $num*$num2;
    }

    else{
        echo '';
    }


    ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```